# Multiple Thread Access a Collection in .net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Supposed there is something like Hashtable created by Hashtable.Synchronized() which is accessed by multiple thread. and the key value pair is Guid and Object in Hashtable .
One of thread need to polling this Hashtable until a specific Guid key had been added into this list by another thread.

Below is my code .

```
        public Hashtable syncHt = new Hashtable();
        public void Init()
        {
            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            syncHt = Hashtable.Synchronized(ht);
        }
```

In the application initialization i will call the init();

And In one of thread I will call isExist to find the specific Guid which is added by some other thread .

```
public bool isExist(Guid sId)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (syncHt.ContainsKey(sId))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

}
```

I was wondering whether this loop could be ended. How can I know the Hashtable changed during the polling ?Thanks

Comment: Not sure there isn't such a thing but you can create your own class and use the SychronizationAttribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no direct equal in .NET - however the `Interlocked` class provides a lot of the same functionality, like exchange, etc.

Comment: Hi .all . thank you for the comments . I had edited my question .

Comment: Did you know that a Guid is not a reference type?

Comment: I think you need the ConcurrentBag http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and more important assigning to a reference is always atomic in .NET.

To do atomic operation, use the `System.Threading.Interlocked` class. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7etff8w.aspx)

---

> I was wondering whether this loop could be ended.

It will end when another (only 1 writer allowed) thread inserts the wanted value, yes.

On MSDN:  [Hashtable is thread safe for use by multiple reader threads and a single writing thread.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)

But your solution is very inefficient. The busy-loop can consume a lot of CPU time for nothing. Storing (boxed) Guids in an old style collection isn't perfect either.

Comment: Hope a better solution for this scenario. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/03/a-parable.aspx) and then post a new question.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818322/multiple-thread-access-a-collection). thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [concurrent collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108), especially on `ConcurrentBag<T>`

**Update**

About IsExist, here is better solution

Change `Hashtable`on `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object>`so no lock required

Add items to `repository`without any lock

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object> repository = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object>();
```

Check repository for existing items

```
    public bool IsExist(Guid id)
    {
        SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => repository.ContainsKey(id)); - you can add Timout
        return true;
    }
```

Here is more about [SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289501)

Comment: How do i know the ConcurrentBag is changed when I loop the Collections in a method ?thanks