# Multiple Thread Access a Collection

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency

Supposed there is collection which is accessed by multiple thread.  One of thread needs to know a given item had been added by another thread. Can anyone give a solution to make it ? Thanks.

Comment: You can clarify "One of thread needs to know a specific item had been added by another thread" - do you just need to know when something is added to the collection (like an observable collection), or do you really need to know if it came from a different thread?

Comment: I need to do something after I know a given item was added into collection by other threads. Just as you means like an observable collection. We can say one read thread to observe the collection and many writer thread to change the collection.Thanks .

Comment: The question states "specific item".  Please correct the question.

Comment: You can use events. But events send notification to objects, not to threads. Threads are not well suited to be notified. They could wait for something but that's wasting a thread. You're still asking for a ruler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a thread safe collection

[Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)

As for knowing what thread added specific item I don't think an item tracks the tread.  I think you could add a Property TheadName and have the thread enter that value.

The question states "specific item had been added".  Then in comment the OP infers any item.

.NET does not have thread safe ObservableCollection.  There are some on codeplex or possible rethink you design.  ConcurrentQueue may be an option.

Comment: For clarity I think you mean any item.   Are you sure you can't do this with a queue.  When the queue processes and items it could add it to an ObservableCollection.